# How to use pruned weight or model?

Tags: pytorch, pruning

I'd like to use the pruned model and weight but,
whenever I load the model or weight, this error messages keep popping up... My weight and model's files:

[image]

Error messages

[image]

Comment: Please add error messages as text rather than images.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you have this error is that some weights present in the file you are trying to load have no corresponding parts in the initialized model (since it has been pruned). One quick way to go around that is to silent the warnings with the [`strict=False`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Module.html?highlight=load_state_dict#torch.nn.Module.load_state_dict) option:

```
model.load_state_dict(state_dict, strict=False)
```

You can actually store the result of that call and log the missing and unexpected modules found in the file.